# NSFetchedResultsController to return objects with unique property

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a properly set up `NSFetchedResultsController` that returns all the objects I want. However, I want to set it up so that it returns only objects that are unique by `ID` value, because there are several duplicate objects that have the same `ID` but other different properties in the DB.

I tried to set it up like the documentation says and ended up with this result:

```
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"eventCategoryID", @"eventName", @"eventID", @"eventPeopleCount", @"eventPrice", @"eventCrewCount", @"eventStartDateTS", @"eventImageURL", @"shouldShowFriends", @"isLiked"];
```

However they say that you have to use this property only with `NSDictionaryResultType`. And moreover, it gives me a strange crash.

What are the approaches to make objects returned by `NSFetchedResultsController` filtered so as to have a custom unique property like ID?

Comment: "A strange crash"? What's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to find all the objects where the `ID` property is unique? Then yes, NSDictionaryResultType is the way to go. I think you will need two fetches, though.

First, build a fetch request to retrieve all of the `ID` values, and a count for each value. Use NSExpressionDescription to apply the `@count` function to your results, and use an NSDictionaryResultType. Group by `ID`. A step by step example is at http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/ios-core-data-group-by-and-count-results/.

Now you'll have a dictionary with keys for `ID` and the count of that `ID`. Filter that dictionary so that you only have `ID`s where the count was 1, and extract just those `ID` values. Now you can build a second fetch request based on `ID IN ...` your array of singleton `ID`s.

It might be possible to build a more complicated original fetch request to return only the count=1 `ID`s.